# Should lights on a three-way circuit connect to the switch with the power cable attached?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to install 3 way wiring for recessed lights in living room.  After some google search, I found 2 options (look at pictures) for my situation to do it. In first one, LINE and LOAD is at same switch. In second one, LINE and LOAD at different switch. Can someone tell me if there is any standard or best practices for this?  Which option should I choose ?

[image: LINE and LOAD at same switch]

[image]

Comment: This is usually determined by the topography of the situation. One approach often requires less cable. It really doesn't matter, so it's down to that and personal preference.

Comment: Along those ^ lines, if this is a new install, do it in a way that uses the least amount of wiring because that will be the cheapest. If it's a replacement, do it the way it was done previously because it will be much easier to follow the existing wiring path instead of tearing open walls to make a new one, thus cheapest, quickest, easiest.

Comment: There are actually at least 5 possible arrangements to wire a 3-way circuit. Both of these methods are compatible with modern Code using /3 cables.  The other methods would require /4 cable, or conduit, to satisfy the "neutral to switches" 2011 Code requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to connect 3 way switches.  I always prefer the 2nd method you posted. There is no "code taping" needed, since all the wires are already the correct color.   The 2nd method is so simple and straightforward:  Power in to one switch, x/3 to the next switch then to the fixtures.   Sometimes it's not practical due to length of runs (takes too much wire), but I'll do it that way every time if possible.

Comment: Note that this answer is 100% correct and based entirely on opinion. It is a _preference_ for one over the other, except when that preference isn't practical. Hence, there is NO "should" as asked by the OP.

Comment: @FreeMan  I really appreciate this site and the learning I get here. But I think sometimes the rules are pretty aggressively enforced.  The OP, in his last sentence clearly asked if there was a best practice or standard way. Yes, my answer was opinion based, but geeze, it was also a decent answer.  I answered the OPs question.   If SE is going to be so uptight about this, I'll be reconsidering my participation here.

Comment: @FreeMan  Additionally:  Had the OP asked "How do I wire 3 way switches?"  I would probably provided a very similar response, including the 2nd diagram. Would that have been opinion based? Is my answer "opinion based" only because the OP asked which wiring method was best?   Pretty narrow rules.

Comment: Questions asking for "best" have been pretty aggressively closed as opinion based for a while now. On the one hand, there usually is no "best" (though many would consider backstabs to be the "worst"), on the other hand, for a new to DIY, I certainly understand the desire for "best practices". These types are, sometimes, reworded as what are the pros/cons of these two methods, which are usually left open. Hair splitting, I know, but that's how it seems to be. And, +1 for your answer from me, BTW.

Comment: @FreeMan  I would think that most ppl that come here want the "best" answer to their question. Few come here asking, "What's the cheapest way to hookup this sub-panel, I don't give a wit about electrical code, I just want to do it on the cheap".   Of course a question like this would get shouted down very quickly, but the original question, according to SE's rules, would be a "how to" question, not a "what's best" question.   Am I making sense?  I don't want to belabor this and have chat like discussion in comments, so I'll shut up for a while!  Take care and stay safe.

Comment: @FreeMan  Actually I'd like to politely make one more comment.  Most comments and answers have a high degree of opinion in them. Tons of questions like "I have a shop that's an outbuilding and want to run power to it. What's best?" After various clarifications as to needs and loads, there is usually a few good answers, but many times people comment or answer, "since you're digging a trench, run conduit, not direct bury cable"  or "put in a larger sub-panel that you think you'll need". Both are highly opinionated. Food for thought.